# Converting nested list into nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, nested

I have this list:

```
list1 = [['X1',2],['X2',4],['Y1',2],['Y2',4]]
```

and I want to create this dict:

```
dict1 = {'X': {'1':2},{'2':4},'Y':{'1':2},{'2':4}}
```

so that I can use `dict1['X']['1']` and this outputs `'2'`

Can someone help me out? I've tried multiple approaches but without any success.

Comment: What you present as the desired structure for `dict` is not a legal Python dictionary. All elements in a dictionary must be key : value pairs (separated by `:`). The pairs should be separated from others with commas. In you example, some of the supposed dictionary entries are, themselves, dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> list1 = [['X1',2],['X2',4],['Y1',2],['Y2',4]]
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for (c,i), n in list1:
...     d[c][i] = n
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'X': {'1': 2, '2': 4}, 'Y': {'1': 2, '2': 4}})
>>> d['X']['1']
2
```

Comment: I didn't know we can unpack variables in such a way. That's great! It's also worth to mention that it wouldn't work without parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

`dict1 = {'X': {'1':2},{'2':4},'Y':{'1':2},{'2':4}}` is syntax-wise illegal.

Assuming you meant `{'X': {'1': 2, '2': 4}, 'Y': {'1': 2, '2': 4}}`

```
In [1]: list1 = [['X1',2],['X2',4],['Y1',2],['Y2',4]]

In [2]: unique_letters = {k[0] for k, _ in list1}

In [3]: unique_letters
Out[3]: {'X', 'Y'}

In [4]: dict1 = {k: {} for k in unique_letters}

In [5]: for k, v in list1:
    ...:     dict1[k[0]][k[1]] = v
    ...:

In [6]: dict1
Out[6]: {'X': {'1': 2, '2': 4}, 'Y': {'1': 2, '2': 4}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's what I meant, my apologies!